# Python A way to split a file into sections every time a newline appears in python and manipulate the sections

Tags: python

I have a plain text file in a particular format, for simplicity here, lets keep the order as name,age,hobbies then a space, and it goes on as such.

name1
age1
Cricket and Chess

name2
age2
Cricket, Tennis and Hockey

etc etc it goes on till say name1000

I am trying to write a python program which can take this file convert it to and save the output to a new file as 
Hi name1. You are aged age1 years. You like Cricket and Chess
Hi name2. You are aged age2 years. You like Cricket, Tennis and Hockey
and so on

Since I was not able to do it I tried to do this for a small sample of 2 where I added these(Name:,Age:,Hobbies:) before them

Name : name1
Age : age1
Hobbies : Cricket,Chess

Name : name2
Age : age2
Hobbies : Cricket, Tennis and Hockey

And I have made the code below.But unable to do it properly and the code below is just another unscuccessful attempt.

```
import re
number = 1
doc = open('profiles.txt', 'r')

def combine(line):
  x = ''
  if re.search("^Name :", line): x = str((line.partition(':'))[2])
  elif re.search("^Age :", line): x = str((line.partition(':'))[2])
  elif re.search("^Hobbies :", line): x = str((line.partition(':'))[2])
  else : pass
  return x
 
for n in doc: 
    # with open('Result.txt', 'a') as file: file.write(str("{0}) Hi {1}. You are aged{1}. You like{1}".format(number,str(combine(n)))))
    print(str("{0}) Hi {1}. You are aged{1}. You like{1}".format(number,str(combine(n)))))
    number += 1
```

I have tried searching for answers but perhaps I don't know to word it correctly or something.
Any help is appreciated a lot!

Comment: It seems like you are allowed to modify the file format. Why don't you turn it into json then? Array of objects. It would be really easy to manipulate

Comment: Agreed! But I still have little experience in JSON. But thanks for your input! I shall learn it in the future!

Comment: JSON format is not complex at all. You should invest about an hour in getting familiar with it and be happy for the rest of your life. It's not a good practice to use self-defined formats unless it's really necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first instance where you have line break separated details, you can do:

```py
file_name = "./details.txt"

def print_details(name, age, hobbies):
    """Helper function to print the details in a nice format"""
    print(f"Hi {name}. You are aged {age}. You like {hobbies}")
    
# add details to a list until a newline is reached, print then reset
with open(file_name, 'r') as fin:
    details = []
    for line in fin:
        if line == '\n':
            print_details(*details)
            details = []
        else:
            details.append(line.strip())
    print_details(*details)
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a ton. I shall learn the method you have described!

Comment: Great, glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a simpler approach (based on the second file format that you suggest):-

```
DEFAULT = {'Name': '', 'Age': '', 'Hobbies': ''}
with open('/Users/andy/profiles.txt') as p:
    d = dict(DEFAULT)
    for line in p:
        line = line.rstrip('\n').strip()
        if len(line) == 0:
            print(
                f'Hi {d["Name"]}. Your age is {d["Age"]}. You like {d["Hobbies"]}')
            d = dict(DEFAULT)
        else:
            t = line.split(':')
            if len(t) == 2:
                d[t[0].strip()] = t[1].strip()
```

Comment: Thanks for your point of view, but it is a cumbersome process to rename all the files I have! Nevertheless I am thankful for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by renaming files!. Also, there may be more code here than in other solutions but it's more robust and thus accounts for a malformed input file

Answer (score 0):

Another version, pedantic with the file format you provided, using *.readlines()*

readlines() reads all the lines in a single run and then return them as string elements in a list that you can iterate and scrape over very easily.

```
with open('text_file.txt', 'r') as file1:
lines = file1.readlines()
 
i = 0
if i <= (len(lines)-3):
    while i in range(len(lines)):
        print (f"Hello, your name is {lines[i][:-1]}, you are {lines[i+1][:-1]} years old and you likes: {lines[i+2][:-1]}")
        i +=4
```

My text_file is:

```
Mario
45
Cricket and Chess

Tobia
15
Cricket, Tennis and Hockey

Steve Tyler
70
Sex, Drugs, RocknRoll
```

It prints out:

```
Hello, your name is Mario, you are 45 years old and you likes: Cricket and Chess
Hello, your name is Tobia, you are 15 years old and you likes: Cricket, Tennis and Hockey
Hello, your name is Steve Tyler, you are 70 years old and you likes: Sex, Drugs, RocknRoll
```